# SQLite Exception in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In my Universal App for Windows 8.1 (Store) and Windows Phone 8.1 I have an exception at opening a data base only in the Store App. The code is shared for both, and for Windows Phone it is working.

```
class MemoDB
{
    public static SQLiteConnection conn;

    public MemoDB() { 
        conn = LoadDatabase();
    }

    static private SQLiteConnection LoadDatabase()
    {
       // Get a reference to the SQLite database
       conn = new SQLiteConnection("ct_history.sqlite");
    ...
    }
}
```

The exception {"Unable to set temporary directory."} occurs at the last shown line of code, details are this:

```
SQLitePCL.SQLiteException was not handled by user code.
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Unable to set temporary directory.
  Source=SQLitePCL
  StackTrace:
       at SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection.SetTemporaryDirectory()
       at SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String fileName, Boolean setTemporaryDirectory)
       at SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String fileName)
       at CTDICT.MemoDB.LoadDatabase()
       at CTDICT.MemoDB..ctor()
       at CTDICT.Dictionary..ctor()
       at CTDICT.CTDICT_Windows_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_8_Dictionary()
       at CTDICT.CTDICT_Windows_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
  InnerException: SQLitePCL.SQLiteException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Unable to open the database file: :memory:
       Source=SQLitePCL
       StackTrace:
            at SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String fileName, Boolean setTemporaryDirectory)
            at SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection.SetTemporaryDirectory()
       InnerException: System.DllNotFoundException
            HResult=-2146233052
            Message=DLL "sqlite3.dll": The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) can not be loaded.
            Source=SQLitePCL.Ext
            TypeName=""
            StackTrace:
                 at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider.NativeMethods.sqlite3_open(IntPtr filename, IntPtr& db)
                 at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider.Sqlite3Open(IntPtr filename, IntPtr& db)
                 at SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String fileName, Boolean setTemporaryDirectory)
            InnerException:
```

It seems to me that "DLL sqlite3.dll: The specified module could not be found" is pointing to the problem. I've checked the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\SQLite.WinRT81\3.8.5\" and found that DLL in all configurations (ARM, x64, x86).

References to SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) (Version 3.8.5.0) and SQLitePCL (v4.0.30319) are properly set.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 5):

Even if I had done it several times already, I deleted the reference for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) again. But this time I have deleted the reference for Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows also. After I had both added again, the problem was gone.

Comment: Lucky you. I am facing similar problem in UWP app, [unable to load dll sqlite3.dll the specified module could not be found inuwp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521860/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-in-uwp)