# Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3.dll': The specified module could not be found in UWP Xamarin.Forms

Tags: sqlite, azure, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to write app for UWP Xamarin.Forms with use of [Azure Mobile SQLiteStore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore) package.

I struggle with SQLitePCL package which is dependency of that mentioned above package.

In my UWP project I referenced extension SQLite for Universal Windows Platform also it's dependency Microsoft.VCLibs

**Error is** : Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Android app works fine, only UWP has this problem crashing app as soon as it start to call SQLite.

**And Stacktrace:**

```
at SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection.SetTemporaryDirectory()
at SQLitePCL.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String fileName, SQLiteOpen openFlag, Boolean setTemporaryDirectory)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore..ctor(String fileName)
at WellDoneIt.Services.WellDoneItMobileService.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at WellDoneIt.Services.WellDoneItMobileService.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at WellDoneIt.ViewModel.ListViewModel.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at WellDoneIt.ViewModel.ListViewModel.<<-ctor>b__2_2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__6_0(Object state)
at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

**Update**:
I have also double checked processor architecture and for emulator it is set to x86, and for real Win10 Mobile device it is set to ARM.

On both getting exactly the same issue. However when I run my app on local machine (my Windows 10 OS I develop on) everything works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you're not using Any CPU for your build output. It should be x86 or ARM depending on what you're running on.

Comment: Got that sorted. For emulator x86 and for real device ARM, in UWP project. For PCL DLL I got AnyCPU, I think that's correct setup. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference to SQLite for windows platforms.

On your UWP project go to Add References.

Go to Universal Windows > Extensions

Then make sure you tick SQLite for Universal App Platform

Comment: Thanks for answer. 

I am aware of this extension for UWP and Windows 8 apps. Got latest version of it, same to VC++ dependency, all are referenced to my project, but for some reason I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled for hours with what could be the same problem.

I upgraded the SQLite to the latest version and I think this is where the problem began.

I downloaded Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, ran and selected modify. Then ensured all the highlighted updates were ticked and the deprecated items are un-ticked. (Update 2 is included in the latest community download)

I hope this works for you.

Comment: What you mean from your answer is to download latest community VS 2015? If so I must tell you that my problems start to happen right after fresh install of system and VS2015 Update 2 downloaded few days ago. 

Before I was developing on my old windows installation with older but constantly updated VS2015 Community and everything was working. When I needed to reinstall my system (for some other not related problems). I installed latest VS2015 Update 2 from web, with tools needed for Xamarin, and made all necessary updates. Then this problem hit me... Thanks for answer though.

Comment: Mine must have been a different problem, also for your information there appears to be issues related to this on the SQLite website but no solutions were offered. Good luck.

Comment: Can you share link here, can't find anything related there. Thanks

Comment: Sorry cannot find it now.
FYI. I am using.
SQLite.UWP.2015, Version=3.12.1 and  Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps,